# How can I install pyqula in jupiternotebook?

Tags: installation

"I installed pyqula, but I'm getting a message in the CMD saying they are not installed. What should I do?"

I installed pyqula but when i want to run code in jupiter notebook i have error: #plt.savefig("vacancy2.jpg")
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement